# ALT + CTRL / ALT +CTRL+SHIFT or any combination of these keys for shortcuts is not working

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have searched all across the web but found no help for this issue. I am using HP folio 9470m EliteBook with Ubuntu 20.04 installed. A few months ago everything was working like charm but now i am facing a problem that any shortcut which needs combination of these key i-e for Terminal in Linux we have to press CTRL+ALT+T but my laptop isn't supporting the shortcuts like this. Similarly, if we look at Intelij and we need to press CTRL+SHIFT+Z for redo. Although these shortcuts can be modified but it becomes overhead to change each of the shortcut. I assure you that my keyboard don't have any problem like if i try to do any thing with individual key i-e CTRL+C copies the content SHIFT toggles the case while i have modified the shortcut for terminal to ALT+T and it is also working. The only issue is the combination of these keys isn't working. Looking forward for response, and thank you in advance.